# How to kill an application that thrashes hdd?

Tags: hard-disk

Is there a known way/application to kill applications that thrash HDD, like `early-oom` does for RAM?

Comment: What I meant by "trashing an HDD" is "writing to hdd too much, too frequently". See https://www.webopedia.com/definitions/disk-thrashing/

Comment: Ah, "_thrashing_" is a different word to "_trashing_". To thrash is to beat unremittingly; to trash is to break or destroy

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use cgoups/cgroups2 to limit the io a single process is allowed to do over some defined averaging time.

If you really want to kill (rather than just to throttle drastically), you could epbf attach to the cgroups events that happen when your process goes into io saturation.